# Git merge child back to parent... both files conflict

Tags: git, merge

So I started by branching to a new branch from master:

`git checkout -b branchA`

While in `branchA` I branched to `branchB` because I wanted the changes in `branchA` already.

When I got done with `branchB` I wanted to fold the changes back to `branchA`. What I found was that all the files that I had touched in `branchA` but not in `branchB` were now in conflict with itself - the lines that were changed in `branchA` now show up as conflicts after I did a `git merge branchB` from `branchA`.

What's the proper way to merge these changes?

By the way I have already pushed to remote, so I don't know if rebase will work here.

Comment: How did you "fold" the changes from `branchB` into `branchA`?

Comment: `git checkout branchA`; `git merge branchB`

Comment: Please review the answers given below, thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After you

```
git checkout -b branchA
```

You probably made some changes while having `branchA` checked out.  When you were done, you probably did something like

```
git checkout -b branchB
```

Now you've checked out `branchB`.  You made some more changes on `branchB`.  When you are done with whatever you want to do on `branchB`, you want to merge those changes to `branchA`.  So you do

```
git checkout branchA
git merge branchB
```

If you have any merge conflicts, they would come up right now.  But unless someone else has made changes to `branchA` (or you made changes to `branchA`), you wouldn't have any conflicts.

Up to now, the branches have only existed locally on your machine.  If you want to push them onto your remote server, you would do

```
git push origin branchA //Assuming you have branchA checked out on your local
```

If you want to push `branchB` onto the remote server, you would checkout `branchB` and use the same command.

Comment: can I directly merge branchB to master and discard changes in branchA ?

Answer (score 0):

From what you mentioned, your observations are the expected behavior from Git.  You made some changes to files in `branchA` **after** creating `branchB`, then you tried merging `branchB` into `branchA`.  The source of the merge conflict is that there are two versions of each of these files in conflict, one from `branchB` and the other from `branchA`.

Normally, you would open up the file in question in an editor or IDE, and look for conflict markers like this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
version in branchA
=======
version in branchB
>>>>>>>
```

Choose the correct version, then commit the file.  Since you already pushed, please verify that the version of files in `branchA` are what you actually want.

Answer (score -3):

Ahh sorry. It turns out `branchA` has a ton of changes since `branchB` was made. Hence all of these conflicts. Thanks everybody.